# How to play music on PAM8610 with ESP32?

Tags: amplifier, audio, power-amplifier, esp32, digital-audio

I'm trying to use Xtronical's DAC audio library on an ESP32 to run 10W speakers. The board that Xtronical used is a PAM8403 which has a signal voltage range of -0.3V to +0.3V but as it can only run 3W speakers thus I cannot use it. 
Hence, I am using a PAM8610 which can drive 10W speakers. The problem is that I don't know what its signal voltage range is. Can anyone help me in this regard?

If the range is different than that of PAM8403, then how can I map my ESP32 output to this range?

[image: PAM8610 Amplifier Module]

References:

1. https://www.xtronical.com/driving-a-speaker/
2. https://www.xtronical.com/adding-amplified-sound-simple-version/
3. https://www.xtronical.com/the-dacaudio-library-download-and-installation/

Comment: And i know that only esp32 only gives a positive output. so only need to know to how to map the output voltage to the positive side of the range.

Answer (score 2):

Both amplifiers use an input coupling capacitor to block DC from your esp32.
The datasheet for the PAM8610 shown a maximum input of -0.3V to +6V and since it needs an input coupling capacitor its input is probably already biased at +3V. It uses a DC volume control that your amplifier module does not use. Its inputs are line level.

The datasheet for the PAM8403 shows a maximum input of -0.3V to Vdd PLUS 0.3V so the input  voltage range is almost the same as the PAM8610.

The PAM8610 produces 5W to 8W per channel at low distortion into 8 ohm speakers when the supply is +12VDC. The IC will overheat when driving 4 ohm speakers.

Comment: so should i use a voltage divider to map esp32 0-3.3v volts to 0-0.3v volts if i am using PAM8610?

Comment: and PAM8610 can also drive 10W and 15W speakers, with 8 ohm and 4 ohm loads respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Both amplifiers use an input coupling capacitor to block DC.
The datasheet for the PAM8610 shown a maximum input of -0.3V to +6V and since it needs an input coupling capacitor its input is probably already biased at +3V. It uses a DC volume control.

The datasheet for the PAM8403 shows a maximum input of -0.3V to Vdd PLUS 0.3V so the input  voltage range is almost the same as the PAM8610.

The PAM8610 produces 5W to 8W per channel at low distortion into 8 ohm speakers when the supply is +12VDC. The IC will overheat when driving 4 ohm speakers.